# Access other user's mailbox to get his folder structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

How is it possible to get a specific user's folder structure without using the ExchangeService with it password?

I surely have the rights to read the information but can't find a way to do that. I'm searching for something like that:

```
Mailbox userMailbox = new Mailbox(user);

WellKnownFolderName userFolderName = userMailbox.WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot;

FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults = exchangeService.FindFolders(userFolderName, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
```

But actually I cannot access to other WellKnowFolderNames or directly to his folders.

**Edit**: I had a new approach but unfortunately it didn't return any items:

```
// Create mailbox for user
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(user);

// Create a searchfolder to verify the used folder id is the same like the given folder id
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo folderIdFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.Id, folderId);

// Create new folder id
FolderId usersFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, mailbox);

// Find items with search criteria
itemResult = getExchangeService().FindItems(usersFolderId, folderIdFilter, viewBase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
itemResult = getExchangeService().FindItems(usersFolderId, folderIdFilter, viewBase);
```

Would only access the Items in the Root folder which for most mailboxes there won't be anything there. All you need to do is use the FolderId overload and the FindFolders eg

```
        FolderId RootFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, "MailboxtoAccess@domain.com");
        FolderView FolderVw = new FolderView(1000);
        FolderVw.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults = null;
        do
        {
            findFoldersResults = service.FindFolders(RootFolder, FolderVw);
            foreach (Folder mbFolder in findFoldersResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing Folder " + mbFolder.DisplayName);
            }
            FolderVw.Offset += findFoldersResults.Folders.Count;
        } while (findFoldersResults.MoreAvailable);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine! Do you probably know, how to do the same process for getting all items of a specific user? The problem is in that situation, I cannot set the FolderId to the mailbox, because I have to use a given FolderId to find all items within this folder of a specific user.

Comment: If you want to get All items in a Mailbox the best approach is just enumerate the Items in Each folder (using findItems), eg in the above example place something inside the Foreach Loop. Paging will restrict you to processing item in batches of 1000. If you just want to search for an Item in a Mailbox the Ediscovery in 2013 and above can be used to find an item or items in a mailbox that meet a search criteria  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190897(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I can use that at another point, but what I meant something different: I've an folderId in a mailbox and want to get all items which are in that mailbox. I don't know if all folder Ids are globally unique, then I could simply search for that folder and get its items. But are folder Ids unique across all mailboxes?

Comment: Yes the FolderId is global unique eg its all you need to bind to a folder in a Mailbox. If you want to get all items in a Mailbox all you need is the Mailbox SMTP then bind to and enumerate the Folders and then the Item. Store EWSId's isn't a great idea as they can change see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: All right, thanks for you answer! I assume that the ID changes just affect the Item IDs and not the folder IDs, but the way I handle it will always keep items updated so changes should be noticed of the system.